# What is the purpose of LVCOLUMN.cchTextMax and LVITEM.cchTextMax?

Tags: c, listview, winapi

I have tried to set the values of `LVCOLUMN.cchTextMax` and `LVITEM.cchTextMax` to a random value (less than the corresponding string length) and it worked, did it work by mistake or these fields are not necessary to set?

I have also seen examples that do not use these fields, for example: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9148/C-functions-to-insert-columns-items-and-subitems-i

Comment: Its a field that's populated when you *receive* that struct from an API call, its irrelevant when dispatching it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for the [LVITEM structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774760.aspx) has the following to say on the `cchTextMax` member:

> This member is only used when the structure receives item attributes. It is ignored when the structure specifies item attributes. For example, **cchTextMax** is ignored during [**LVM_SETITEM**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761186.aspx) and [**LVM_INSERTITEM**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761107.aspx). It is read-only during [LVN_GETDISPINFO](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774818.aspx) and other LVN_ notifications.

Unless you are using this structure to retrieve item information, this member is ignored. When receiving data you have to pass a pointer to a buffer to `pszText`, and communicate its size through the `cchTextMax` member.

This is a common pattern throughout the Windows API, where the same structure is used to set and query values. The semantics of the individual members depend on the direction. Other common structures, that are used in a similar fashion include [TVITEM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773456.aspx) or [MENUITEMINFO](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647578.aspx), for example.